# Rendering bootstrap modal using backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

I think a code will explain better my problem:
the View:

```
App.Views.ErrorModal = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: window.template('errorModal'),

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

    this.$("#errorApproveModal").modal({
        keyboard: true
    });

    return this;

  }

});
```

when instantiating:

```
 var error = new App.Models.Errors({title: "Exporting Error", content: "Error"});
 var errorModal = new App.Views.ErrorModal({model: error});
 errorModal.render();
```

The modal is loaded but i get only an empty div

Thanks for the help!
Roy

Comment: Does the problem come from the template or the modal method?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It always better to create a separate class that holds all Modal logic and then call it from the master view.

Try using [this approach](https://gist.github.com/andrewshatnyy/6126879).

**Modal JS**

```
var BaseModalView = Backbone.View.extend({

    id: 'base-modal',
    className: 'modal fade hide',
    template: 'modals/BaseModal',

    events: {
      'hidden': 'teardown'
    },

    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'show', 'teardown', 'render', 'renderView');
      this.render();
    },

    show: function() {
      this.$el.modal('show');
    },

    teardown: function() {
      this.$el.data('modal', null);
      this.remove();
    },

    render: function() {
      this.getTemplate(this.template, this.renderView);
      return this;
    },

    renderView: function(template) {
      this.$el.html(template());
      this.$el.modal({show:false}); // dont show modal on instantiation
    }
 });
```

**Handlebars template**

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

**Parent View**
    // on button click following fired

```
modalView = new BaseModalView();
modalView.show();

// Modal view automatically bound to the body and removes itself on hidden;
```

Comment: This worked great for displaying my modal from a parent view.  However, I'm having trouble with the teardown.  It seems the 'hidden' event is never called.  I can explicitly call the function by capturing my close button's click event, but then it loses the nice fade out effect.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you use Bootsrap 3 please make sure that your view listens to     "hidden.bs.modal".


Guys changed the name of the event with new version of Bootsrap http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I am getting error as `Object [object Object] has no method 'modal' ` For line `                this.$el.modal('show');
`. Any idea?

Comment: Please look at getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals. Modal implementation.

Comment: Where is getTemplate defined?

Comment: It's a custom function on prototype You could just use JST['template']()

`Backbone.View.prototype.getTemplate = function(name, callback) {
callback.call(this, JST[name]);
}`

It's abstracted to a method for cases when templates are fetched async.

Comment: @AndrewShatnyy Seems good solution. Can't figure out how to pass data to modal template though. Can you suggest a way ?

Comment: Passing data to template happens in render method so you can construct `data` object and pass it to template function.

`var data = {prop1: 'Property'};`


`this.$el.html(template(data));`

Comment: @vini you have newer version of underscore. I've updated the code for you to work on both versions. Reference http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll

Comment: Please help me with this issue someone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182787/multiple-modals-being-added-in-backbone/

Comment: `className: 'modal fade'` - that is, without `hide`.

Comment: @user115202, feel free use classes you prefer. Code above is just an example and should be taken as a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

### A simple bootstrap modal -

We can extend this view to add more functionality to it. Also we can pass data to view on init.

#### View file

```js
/**
 * ModalView
 * @version 0.0.1
 */
var ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tpl: JST['modal-tpl'],
  className: 'modal-view',
  events: {
    'evt:show': 'show',
    'evt:hide': 'hide',
  },
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = options;
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'show', 'hide', 'remove');
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {

    this.$el.html(this.tpl(this.options));
    this.$el.appendTo('body');
    this.$modal = this.$('.modal');

    this.$modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', _.bind(function() {
      this.close();
    }, this));


  },
  show: function() {
    this.$modal.modal('show');
  },
  hide: function() {
    this.$modal.modal('hide');
  },
  close: function() {
    //unbind events
    this.unbind();
    //Remove html from page
    this.remove();
  },

});
```

#### To open modal -

```js
//Pass modal data on init
var modal = new ModalView({
  modalContent: 'Hello User!'
});
modal.show();
//modal.trigger('evt:show');
```

#### Handlebar template for v3 -

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-label">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-label">Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {{{modalContent}}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- On modal hidden - we have to remove modal html, events to avoid multiple instances.
- Bootstrap modal HTML should be appended to body - if not you may face issues with z-index/backdrop.

Comment: Thank you sharing this @mohan. I would like to know how can we perform action only when I click on 'OK' in the modal (Let's assume the modal has two buttons - [Ok, Cancel])

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are never adding it to the page.

```
var errorModal = new App.Views.ErrorModal({model: error});
$('#my-div').html(errorModal.el);
errorModal.render();
```

I am assuming bootstrap-modal, like most jquery plugins, requires the html to be on the page before calling it.

Comment: I would've assumed the method would do it. Also, "*The modal is loaded but i get only an empty div*" let me think it is added, but empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the fade and hide classes from your modal view.