# Multiple modals being added in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I am opening the modal from the DetailsView

as follows:

```
    var $ = jQuery = require('jquery'),
  Backbone = require('backbone'),
  Handlebars = require('handlebars'),
  _ = require('underscore'),
  skuDetailsTemplate = require("../../templates/sku/SkuDetails.html"),
  skuDetailsModel = require('../../models/sku/SkuDetailsModel'),
  updateSkuModel = require('../../models/sku/UpdateSkuModel'),
  skuUpdateView = require('../../views/sku/UpdateSkuView'),
  inventoryForFacilityModel = require('../../models/inventory/InventoryForFacilityModel'),
  skuListingModel = require('../../models/sku/listing/SkuListingModel');
var SkuDetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: ".sku-details-container",
  tagName: "div",
  initialize: function (options) {
    var self = this;
    this.skuDetailsModel = new skuDetailsModel();
    this.inventoryForFacilityModel = new inventoryForFacilityModel();
    this.skuListingModel = new skuListingModel();
    this.listenTo(self.skuDetailsModel, 'add', self.render);
    this.listenTo(self.skuDetailsModel, 'change', self.render);
    this.listenTo(self.inventoryForFacilityModel, 'add', self.render);
    this.listenTo(self.inventoryForFacilityModel, 'change', self.render);

    this.listenTo(self.skuListingModel, 'add', self.render);
    this.listenTo(self.skuListingModel, 'change', self.render);


    this.sku_id = options.sku_id;
    this.skuDetailsModel.set("id", this.sku_id);
    this.skuDetailsModel.fetch({});
    this.inventoryForFacilityModel.set("id", this.sku_id);
    this.inventoryForFacilityModel.fetch({})
    this.skuListingModel.set("id", this.sku_id);
    this.skuListingModel.fetch({})
  },
  events: {
    "click .openModal": "openUpdateModal",
    "click .btnEditSku": "openUpdateModal"
  },
  openUpdateModal: function (ev) {
    var data = { model: this.skuDetailsModel };
    var modalView = new skuUpdateView(data);
    modalView.show();
  },
  render: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.$el.html(skuDetailsTemplate({
      skuDetails: self.skuDetailsModel.toJSON(),
      inventoryByFacility: self.inventoryForFacilityModel.toJSON(),
      skuListing: self.skuListingModel.toJSON()
    }));
  }

});

module.exports = SkuDetailsView;
```

ModalView

```
    var UpdateSkuView = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: "modal fade",
  attributes: {
    tabindex: "-1",
    role: "dialog",
  },

  initialize: function (options) {
    var self = this;
    this.model = options.model;
    this.updateSkuModel = new updateSkuModel();
    this.template = skuUpdateTemplate;

  },
  events: {
    "click .save": "saveHandler",
    "click .closeModal": "close",
    "change .clsEdit": "recordModelChange"
  },
  recordModelChange: function (e) {
    var field = e.target.id;
    var value = e.target.value;
    var res = this.model.toJSON();
    var obj = {};

    // if (field === "length" || field === "width" || field === "height" || field === "weight" || field === "mrp" || field === "recommended_selling_price") {
    //   value = parseFloat(value);
    // }
    obj[field] = value;
    obj["id"] = res.records[0].id;
    //var res = this.model.toJSON();

    this.updateSkuModel.set(obj, { validate: true });
  },
  saveHandler: function (e) {
    //Save logic
    var self = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    var options = {
      validate: true,
      success: function (model, response) {
        self.showSuccessMessage("SKU with id " + response.records[0].id + " updated successfully");
        setTimeout(function () {
          self.close();
        }, 1500);

      }
    };
    this.updateSkuModel.save({}, options);
  },
  render: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.$el.html(this.template({
      skuDetails: self.model.toJSON()
    })).modal()

    return this;
  },

  show: function () {
    $(document.body).append(this.render().el);
  },

  close: function () {
    this.$el.remove(".modal fade");
    this.$el.modal("hide");
    this.$el.empty();
    this.undelegateEvents();

  }
});

module.exports = UpdateSkuView;
```

If i open one modal and then close it and then open another instance of the modal it comes over the previous one.

[image]

Please help.

My problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue:

It was because i had multiple instances of my detailsview that the modal was being rendered so many times.

What i did to solve the issue:

Gave a unique `$el` to my `DetailsView`

Answer (score 4):

Vini, your modal view never calls remove http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove either from parent view or from itself.

Modals are pain to keep track of. Exactly for that reason I used [Rendering bootstrap modal using backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085852/rendering-bootstrap-modal-using-backbone/17982356)

Despite all that!
Look at the events you have. You re-render your parent view with out cleaning up the bindings or removing subsequent views.

```
this.listenTo(self.skuDetailsModel, 'add', self.render);
this.listenTo(self.skuDetailsModel, 'change', self.render);
this.listenTo(self.inventoryForFacilityModel, 'add', self.render);
this.listenTo(self.inventoryForFacilityModel, 'change', self.render);

this.listenTo(self.skuListingModel, 'add', self.render);
this.listenTo(self.skuListingModel, 'change', self.render);
```

I sense that `this.listenTo(self.skuListingModel, 'change', self.render);` binds 'click event' every time you re-render / update your "sku"
Remove it and see it works.

Comment: i am calling remove when closing the modal this.$el.remove(".modal fade");

Comment: this.listenTo(self.skuListingModel, 'change', self.render); i removed this however it didn't work.

Comment: step #1 rewrite your modal view with article I recommended that will help you to make sure that you are not leaking Bootsrap modals.
step #2 if you still have that problem then this is your parent view issue. `console.log('render')` in your render method of the parent view to see how many times it's re-rendered.

Comment: Its caling render twice when the issue happens

Comment: Well there's your problem. Your SkuDetailsView has no teardown method that clean up bindings. What you do is just replace SkuDetailsView.el but the previous view is there. Make sure you clean up SkuDetailsView on rerender. Or I would recommend just replace values needed without re-rendering (for now)

Answer (score 1):

I use a modalManager class that extend the Backbone.View for use to show modal views. I think your problem is on the *close* function, you need to hide the modal and then remove it like my *hide* funtion.

```
modalManager = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: "modal",
    template: 'modals/modal.html',
    title: '',
    content: '',
    showButton: true,
    events: {
        'click .close': 'hide',
        'click .btn': 'hide'
    },
    initialize: function (options) {
        _.extend(this, _.pick(options, "title"));
        _.extend(this, _.pick(options, "content"));
        this.render();
    },
    show: function () {
        this.$el.modal('show');
    },
    hide: function () {
        this.$el.modal('hide');
        this.remove();
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template({title: this.title, content: this.content, showButton: this.showButton}));
    },
    setTitle: function(title) {
        this.title=title;
        this.render();
    },
    setContent: function(content) {
        this.content=content;
        this.render();
    },
    setShowButton: function(showbutton) {
        this.showButton=showbutton;
        this.render();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your close-method must be altered:

```
close: function () {
    this.undelegateEvents();
    this.$el.remove();
    this.remove();
}
```

Since you are always creating a new modal the old one is unnecessary (garbage)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please add the `this.$el.remove()` to the close-function.

Comment: still having the same issue.

Comment: is it possible to avoid creating multiple instances of the modal?

Comment: It is possible. You could create a ModalView which is extended by your different modals, which makes sure, that only one of its kind exists.
Another question: If you remove the modals and open a modal a third time, are there then 3 modals opened?

Comment: Ok, so then it is a problem with your event binding. Let's have a look
@vini: Can you add your full detailView to your question?

Comment: I guess the modal view is not garbage collected after it has been closed. Do you see any modal html in the DOM after you close the first modal?

Comment: No nothing is there when i close it

Answer (score 0):

You create a modal instance here:

```
var modalView = new skuUpdateView(data);
```

and here you open it.

```
modalView.show();
```

Modal view can not be garbage collected because it is referenced form another view.

You have to close the modal from the view where you reference it

```
modalView.close();
```